# How to choose between EGARCH and GARCH?

Tags: model-selection, garch

My question is how can we know that we should use GARCH or EGARCH in the empirical study? Can I claim that EGARCH allows for the asymmetric of bad and good news?

I start using the model, but need to study on my own.

Comment: Could you explain more about GARCH and ECHARCH? Maybe add some references? Also, it would really help if you expand more on what the problem is you are solving. For tips on how to write a question, see this guide: https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: @Pieter, GARCH and EGARCH are standard volatility models, I don't think there is a need to expand on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first question essentially is a general question of model selection, and there are numerous good [answers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/model-selection?sort=votes&pageSize=30) on the topic on this site. You would have to filter through the large number of threads to identify the most relevant ones, though; [these ones](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/model-selection+garch) are specifically about GARCH. But the fact that you are choosing between EGARCH and GARCH specifically does not make it very different from choosing between some other models, and the same common principles apply.

You cannot know which model is preferred before you learn some characteristics of your data. E.g. if you observe asymmetric reactions of volatility to positive and negative shocks, then EGARCH may be more suitable than GARCH (because the answer to your second question is a Yes). Generally, you want a model that adequately describes your data without being too complicated. Formally you may compare models using information criteria such as AIC or you may assess out-of-sample forecasting performance.

The answer to your second question is a Yes. You can find a confirmation in any textbook that covers both GARCH and EGARCH, e.g. Tsay ["Analysis of Financial Time Series"](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-EHEP002380.html) (3rd ed., 2010, p. 143).

Comment: Thank you very much Richard .... I start learning the concept of the model on my own. So, that is why my question is a bit broad.  Your response is clear and paves way to another step.   Thank you! :)

Comment: Thank you. This is my first post here, but things may work as same as stackoverflow. :)

Comment: @TomMarverick, Good then! I just wanted to inform you because I tend to anwer lots of questions from new users who are not familiar with the system and many of whom disappear soon after posting the question.

Comment: OK .... Normally, I am a big fan of stackoverflow , and a soon-to-be fan of stackexchange .... Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @TomMarverick, I am glad I could help! Good luck going further with this!